# How can I get the value from sweet alert's text-box

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I would like to create a button that when click it, the sweet alert will pop up and there's the text box in there, and I want to get the text box's value then sent it to my Action through ajax, is that could happen?
code like below thx

```
$("btn").click(function(){
  swal({
     title:'Please text the number',
     text:'You can text more than one',
     content:"input",
     showcancelbutton:'true',
     button{
        text:"Search"    
     }
  }), function(InputData)
    {
       if(InputData === ""){
      swal('Error','You Need To Write Something','error')
    }
   $.ajax({
      url:@Url.action("MyActionName","MyControllerName"),
      method:"Post",
      data: InputData
})
    }
})
```

this is my first post in here , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A complete example I get it from swal website. Follow this same step you will get it:

```
swal({
  text: 'Search for a movie. e.g. "La La Land".',
  content: "input",
  button: {
    text: "Search!",
    closeModal: false,
  },
})
.then(name => {
  if (!name) throw null;
 
  return fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${name}&entity=movie`);
})
.then(results => {
  return results.json();
})
.then(json => {
  const movie = json.results[0];
 
  if (!movie) {
    return swal("No movie was found!");
  }
 
  const name = movie.trackName;
  const imageURL = movie.artworkUrl100;
 
  swal({
    title: "Top result:",
    text: name,
    icon: imageURL,
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  if (err) {
    swal("Oh noes!", "The AJAX request failed!", "error");
  } else {
    swal.stopLoading();
    swal.close();
  }
});
```